# SQL Server 2005 sp_send_dbmail

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sp-send-dbmail

When we use sp_send_dbmail to send email with attachment, the attachment gets copied into a folder inside C:\Windows\Temp. As we have many emails to be sent every day, the temp folder grows rapidly. This is the case with SQL Server 2005. We noticed that, with SQL Server 2008, we dont see these file under temp folder.

Is there any setting to turn the above behavior off?

Does SQL Server 2008 store the files in any other folder and not in temp?

Appreciate your help and time.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to your question, but a possible work around:

How about deleting the older temp files, on a set schedule, to keep the folder smaller?

Comment: jack, thanks. we have already considered this option but curious to know the reason. thanks.